# Open closed window in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, window, open

How can I open the closed window in Chrome? I mean exactly window with all its tabs, but not a single tab. I know that you can open tab by clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

I use:  https://sessionbuddy.com/

It's a Chrome extension - seems minimal resources wise

Been using it for years.  Does the trick. Gives you peace of mind.

(I have no vested interest in the company)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why Ctrl+Shift+T does not satisfy your needs. If you open a new window with a few tabs, and close it, then it will show up in your history.

If you then hit Ctrl+Shift+T, Chrome will re-open the window with its tabs. It is not limited to opening one tab at a time, and I think that is what you seem to believe?

[Here's a picture of the history, after closing a window with multiple tabs. Clicking it, or hitting Ctrl+Shift+T will reopen the window and its tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoPXp.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is to go to "Recently closed" on a new tab. 
You can see [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/aHHE1N5qaag).